# Why AttributeError is generated from this code

Tags: python, auto-indent

I am new in Python and writing a simple Stack class. Please see the code below --

```
 class Stack:
    def __int__(self):
        self.mylist = []

    def push(self, element):
        self.mylist.append(element)

    def pop(self):
        return self.mylist.pop()


myStack = Stack()
myStack.push(1)
```

However, when I run this simple program I am getting the below error --

```
C:\Users\devshankhasharm\PycharmProjects\DataTypes\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/devshankhasharm/PycharmProjects/DataTypes/venv/stack.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/devshankhasharm/PycharmProjects/DataTypes/venv/stack.py", line 13, in <module>
    myStack.push(1)
  File "C:/Users/devshankhasharm/PycharmProjects/DataTypes/venv/stack.py", line 6, in push
    self.mylist.append(element)
AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'mylist'
```

Not sure why it is complaining about mylist attribute. Could it be some indentation issue? I even ran reindent.py over this file but problem still doesn't resolve. Any help is appreciated

Comment: just a typo: your __init function is missing an 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

The initializing method inside a class is named `__init__`

As simple as that!